# NoClassDefFoundError when trying to run a sparql query for Dbpedia in java. (org/slf4j/LoggerFactor)

Tags: java, sparql, noclassdeffounderror, dbpedia

My objective for this program is to run a Sparql query via java and obtain the respective results in the Console.

If i am not wrong, the error is because of a missing jar file. However, in my opinion the required jar files have been added. 
I have added the following jar files : `Jena-2.1.jar` and `arq-2.8.7.jar`.

My code is as follows:

```
public class Example {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    //http request
    String website = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";

    //whatever query we want to parse.
    String query =  "SELECT ?abstract WHERE { { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ronaldo> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract> ?abstract } }";                

    //query execution using the library object.
    QueryExecution queryEx = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(website, query);


    try {
        //results coming from the executed queries.
        ResultSet results = queryEx.execSelect();

        //prints the output.
        for(; results.hasNext();){
            //typecast results from set to qsolution
            QuerySolution answer = (QuerySolution)results.next();

            System.out.println(answer.get("?abstract"));            

        }
    } catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        queryEx.close();
    }
}
```

and the image of the error i am receiving is:

```
<pre>Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.hp.hpl.jena.iri.IRIFactory.jenaImplementation()Lcom/hp/hpl/jena/iri/IRIFactory;
at com.hp.hpl.jena.n3.IRIResolver.<clinit>(IRIResolver.java:42)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.mgt.SystemInfo.createIRI(SystemInfo.java:31)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.mgt.SystemInfo.<init>(SystemInfo.java:23)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ARQ.init(ARQ.java:373)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ARQ.<clinit>(ARQ.java:385)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query.<clinit>(Query.java:53)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:68)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:40)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:28)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(QueryExecutionFactory.java:338)
at Example.main(Example.java:27)<code>
```

Any guidance will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add your code and the excpetion as text not as link to a picture

Comment: Please use a build system like Maven, Ivy or Gradle and also a newer version of Jena.

Comment: thanks a lot for you advice.

Answer (score 1):

jena-2.1 was February 2004. It is not compatible with arq-2.8.7.jar (2010) which used Jena 2.6.4.

It is now 2016. For current releases, see:
http://jena.apache.org/download/

For any jena release (the current one is 3.1.0), you should use all the jars supplied in the distribution. better, as in the comment, learn to use use maven/gradle/... this will happen automatically for you.

Mixing a partial set of jars from different versions is not supported and highly unlikely to work.